# TileJSON layer style based on feature lat/long

Tags: mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

We're using MapboxGL and coming across a need to define a TileJSON layer style based on location. We'd like to filter that style using a feature's latitude and longitude.

For example, let's say we'd like to filter all parks North of the equator and style them differently.

```
...
{
    "id": "parks",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "composite",
    "source-layer": "landuse",
    "filter": [
        "all",
        ["==", "class", "park"],
        [">", "latitude", 0],
   ],
    "layout": {...},
    "paint": {..}
},
...
```

I've tried `latitude` and guesses at other keys for the property name with no success. I understand a polygon feature is not just one point, but am hopeful there is a centroid or some other value that may be of use.

Is this a supported feature of MapboxGL? If so, what property name would we filter with, and where can we find a list of other properties?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what hemisphere-dependent styling are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Steve, this was a contrived example but the issue we are having is that in certain areas the density of our data is too high so we would like to adjust the opacity or color for these areas within a lat/lon bounding box. We control the data from our own tile service so we may have to precompute this and pass additional metadata with the features and then filter using this new property. I was just hopefully that maybe there was some additional special property other than the two documented.

Answer (score 0):

There are [only two special properties](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#types-filter): `$id` and `$type`. So to do any filtering of the sort you describe, you would have to put the attributes directly on your source data. (It's not clear from your question whether you're using Mapbox data, or your own).

To find out what properties are available on Mapbox data, you can just click on a polygon in the add tileset view, and it will show all attributes.